# How to disable CollectionView's vertical gesture recognizer?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer

I am using [LNPopupController](https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNPopupController) framework for presenting View Controllers, the presented VC can be dismissed by dragging it down, however I have added a collection view in this VC and dragging finger in its area doesn't drag the VC down. I want this CollectionView to scroll horizontally, I tried subclassing UICollectionView and use the

```
gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
```

method but it doesn't make any difference.
Here is my code:

```
class MyCollectionView: UICollectionView, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

in `viewDidLoad()`

```
func setupCollection() {
    cellSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.width)
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    }
    //collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false 
    collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
    collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
}
```

when scrolling is disabled everything works perfectly, I can close the view by dragging the CollectionView's area.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would implement `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` in the view controller that contains the collection view:

```
extension MyViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Then you also need to set this delegate to the proper gesture recognizer - in your code I do not see any such line that would assign the delegate to none of the gesture recognizers. I would assign it to the gesture recognizer that is responsible for dismissing the viewController:

```
self.popupContentView.popupInteractionGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
```

Call this line of code in `viewDidLoad` of the `MyViewController` (I use this name since you did not mention the name of your controller). Here I assume that `popupContentView.popupInteractionGestureRecognizer` is the pan gesture recognizer that dismisses the view controller (I checked quickly [LNPopupController](https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNPopupController/tree/master/LNPopupController/LNPopupController)).

Comment: viewForPopupInteractionGestureRecognizer returns UIView, not UIPanGestureRecognizer, and collectionView.panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self causes crash with message "UIScrollView's built-in pan gesture recognizer must have its scroll view as its delegate."

Comment: @Adam can include the code how you present that controller?

Comment: @Adam you just need to find the reference to that gesture recognizer, the one that is responsible for dismissing the view.. I don't use ObjC, so reading the code of the LNPopupController framework is a bit harder for me, but try this: `self.popupContentView.popupInteractionGestureRecognizer.delegate = self`

Comment: popupContentView is a view of the popup bar, not ViewController unfortunately. I will ask the creator, thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Author of `LNPopupController` here.
The other answer is correct. You need to implement the gesture recognizer's delegate and exclude it from interaction (or do even more complex stuff).

To do this, set the `controller.popupContentView.popupInteractionGestureRecognizer.delegate` property. Make sure `controller` is the actual controller you call `presentPopupBarWithContentViewController:animated:completion:` on.